# What Is "Time" When Talking About bigO Notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am getting ahead on next semester classes and just had a question about bigO notation.  What is the time factor measured in? Is it a measure of milliseconds, nanoseconds or just an arbitrary measure based upon the amount of inputs, n, used to compare different versions of algorithims?

Comment: it is not a measure of time. your last statement is correct.

Comment: it's not 'measured' in units of anything. It's simply a measure of asymptotic performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kinda sorta depends on how exactly you define the notation (there are a many different definitions that ultimately describe the same thing). We defined it on turing machines, there time would be defined as the number of computation steps performed. On real machines, it'd be similar - for instance, the number of atomic instructions performed. As some of the comments have pointed out, the unit of time doesn't really matter anyway because what's measured is the asymptotic performance, that is, how the performance changes with increasing input sizes.

Note that this isn't really a programming question and probably not a good fit for the site. More of a CompSci thing, but i think the compsci stackexchange site is meant for post graduates.